# Count and remove Subviews from view in ios

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiview

this is the way I create and add subviews into a view.

I'm wondering why the count always returns 0, when it should return "hundreds". What am I doing wrong, thanks!

I have added more code where shows clearly my issue. I copy/pasted all functions involved on my initial question.

```
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];

        [self.contenedor addSubview:vistaPanelBotones];
        [self crearBotones];
    }

    - (void) crearBotones {
    UIColor *colores[] = {
        [UIColor blueColor],
        [UIColor brownColor],
        [UIColor redColor],
        [UIColor orangeColor],
        [UIColor greenColor],     
        [UIColor yellowColor],
        [UIColor purpleColor],
        [UIColor blackColor],
        [UIColor whiteColor],
        [UIColor darkGrayColor],
        [UIColor magentaColor],
        [UIColor cyanColor],
    };

    int indice = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col < self.vistaPanelBotones.frame.size.width ; col=col+20) {
        for (int fila = 0; fila < self.vistaPanelBotones.frame.size.height-20 ; fila = fila+20) {

            CGRect frame = CGRectMake(col, fila, 20, 20);

            Boton *boton = [Boton new];
            boton.frame = frame;
            boton.layer.backgroundColor = colores[(fila + col) % 7].CGColor;
            boton.layer.cornerRadius = 0.25;
            boton.layer.borderWidth = 0.25;
            boton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
            boton.layer.delegate = self;
            [self.vistaPanelBotones addSubview:boton];
            [boton setNeedsDisplay];    
        }
        indice++;
    }   
    NSLog(@"Vista Botones SubViews:%i",[[self.vistaPanelBotones subviews] count]); 

}

- (IBAction)reiniciar:(id)sender {

    if (self.vistaPanelBotones == nil){
        NSLog(@"no existe la vista"); 
    }
    NSUInteger count = self.vistaPanelBotones.subviews.count;
    NSLog(@"Vista SubViews: %i",count); 

}
```

Comment: When are you running this code? There are important points in a ViewController's lifecycle specific to it's view's geometry. You may not have a valid frame at this point.

Comment: That would give you bad geometry, but a positive subview count.  More likely: self.vistaPanelBotones is nil.  Please log that before you add subview.

Comment: Regarding when I'm running this code, I do it within a function called  in (void)viewDidLoad. It returns 0 at any place of my code. ie I have created am IBaction to just print the number of subviews in a view
- (IBAction)reiniciar:(id)sender {
    
    NSUInteger count = self.vistaPanelBotones.subviews.count;
    NSLog(@"Vista SubViews: %i",count); 
       
}

Comment: Yeah, in viewDidLoad you cannot rely on your frame property. Try moving the code posted here to viewWillAppear and see what the results are.

Comment: tried it also in viewWillAppear and got the same result :-( . I've added more code to review ;) . thanks you all for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few of my thoughts:

1. I would check if self.vistaPanelBotones is non-nil, just in case (if it were nil, you would not get any errors in that code, but also no subviews).
2. Possibly executing this before you have a valid frame (IIRC, viewWillAppear is the earliest callback with valid geometry)
3. I'm pretty sure if boton was nil you would get an exception when adding as a subview, but it's another test worth using for debugging.

Comment: When I call an IBAction through a button in the viewcontroller it doesn't write in logs, so self.vistaPanelBotones isn't nil...

    if (self.vistaPanelBotones == nil){
        NSLog(@"no existe la vista"); 
    }

Answer (score 1):

Use [[self.vistaPanelBotones subviews] count] to count the number of subviews, but there is an elegant way to remove all subviews from a view in Objective-C. Try this:

```
 [[self.vistaPanelBotones subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperView];
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. But this code doesn't work. I've added this:    [[self.vistaPanelBotones subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperView)];
    [self.vistaPanelBotones setNeedsDisplay]; 

however all subviews within a view still display as it nothing happened.